# Update values in pandas dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty pandas dataframe, A, looking like this:

```
col1  col2
 A     nan
 B     nan
 C     nan
```

I want to fill `col2` with values from a different dataframe, B, looking like this:

```
A    B     C
0.4  0.7  0.9
```

Hence the resulting df A should look like:

```
col1  col2
 A     0.4
 B     0.7
 C     0.9
```

I am using more columns in A, hence tranposing is no option. I want to dot it using a for loop using:

```
for i, row in A.iterrows():
    A.at[i, 'col2'] = B.loc[:,B.columns.str.contains(row['col1'])
```

However, this gives my multiple errors, anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.Series.map

```
A['col2'] = A['col1'].map(B.T[0])

  col1  col2
0    A   0.4
1    B   0.7
2    C   0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use pandas merge function where you can transfer the column from one dataframe to another based on common columns or column

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C']})
B = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C'], 'col2':[0.2,0.4,0.3]})
A = pd.merge(A,B, on="col1", how="left")
```

Or If your B dataframe look like this

```
 A    B    C
0.2  0.4  0.3
```

#then the code can be like this

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['col1'] = B.columns
new_df['col2'] = B.iloc[0].values
A = pd.merge(A,new_df, on="col1", how="left")
```